# Does the Tukey HSD test correct for multiple comparisons?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

After performing an ANOVA and then doing post hoc tests with a Tukey HSD test is it still necessary to correct for multiple pairwise comparisons or is that done already?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not necessary to correct for multiple comparisons when using Tukey's HSD. The procedure was developed specifically to account for multiple comparison and maintains experiment-wise alpha at the specified level (conventionally .05). Page 210 of [Maxwell and Delaney's book on experimental design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805837183) has explanations and examples of the procedure.