# Do Tukey and Games-Howell tests need additional p value corrections?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I was reading [documentation of function `posthocTGH`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/userfriendlyscience/versions/0.7.0/topics/posthocTGH) (the "Note" section, where authors expressed doubt about additional corrections to p-values) and linked discussion (particularly [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83941/games-howell-post-hoc-test-in-r#comment543714_112641) answer in which opinion that Games-Howell test does not need additional corrections)
and [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141856/what-is-the-difference-between-various-kruskal-wallis-post-hoc-tests#comment461023_242357) (that Conover-Iman test, which is a posthoc for Kruskal-Wallis tests, needs additional corrections) and got confused.

**My question:** Do (1) Tukey and (2) Games-Howell test (which are posthoc tests for ANOVA) need additional family-wise p-value (e.g., Holm, Bonferroni, etc.) corrections to prevent inflated I type error? Or is it sufficient to use p values of these tests with no additional corrections?

---

UPDATE: it seems that Tukey HSD test does not need additional corrections ([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33360/78115)). Does the same apply to Games-Howell?